# Converting value to MB [bash]

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
VAL1=`ps auxf | grep httpd | grep ^apache | grep -v grep | wc -l`

VAL2=`ps auxf | grep httpd | grep ^apache | grep -v grep | awk '{s+=$6} END {print s}'`

VAL3=`expr $VAL2 / $VAL1`

echo "servers.value $VAL3"
```

and then I have values like `servers.value 63908`. Tell me please, how can i get in in MB?

Comment: Kindly add 3 simple things in your post, 1- sample input, 2- sample output and 3- your efforts which you have put to solve this problem in your post.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide the KiB by 1024 and you get MB:

```
VAL3=`expr $VAL2 / $VAL1 / 1024`

echo "servers.value $VAL3 MB"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get RSS from VAL2 in MB just use:

```
VAL2=`ps auxf | grep httpd | grep ^apache | grep -v grep | awk '{s+=$6} END {print s/1014}'`
```

Comment: Multiplying by `0.001024` is absolutely not equivalent to dividing by 1024.

Comment: PS's VSZ and RSS are output in KiB(kibibytes).
There are 0.001024 megabytes in a Kibibyte :)

Comment: Oh, right, didn't know about that

Comment: However, after reading `ps` manual, I must say that You're right. I see few times KiB, and I always thing that's about Kibibyte. But no, from manual `RSS     - resident set size, the non-swapped physical memory that a task has used (in kiloBytes)`. So the right answer is dividing by 1024.

Comment: You almost never need `grep` and `awk`, even less 3 `grep`s.